# Why is this instance known to the javascript function

Tags: javascript

How can it be that the sampleViewModel instance in the addChangedValue function is not undefined or null ?

From the scope of instantiation the sampleViewModel should not be known in the addChangedValue function as far my understanding is.

```
$(function(){

    var PersonViewModel = function() {
        var me = this;
        me.firstName = ko.observable('Lisa'),
        me.lastName = ko.observable('T'),
        me.changes = ko.observableArray()
    };

    var sampleViewModel = new PersonViewModel();

    sampleViewModel.firstName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        addChangedValue("firstname refreshed: " + newValue);
    });

    function addChangedValue(updatedValue) {
        sampleViewModel.changes.push({ value: updatedValue });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(sampleViewModel, document.getElementById('data'));
});
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most certainly would. Closures are lexically-bound to the scope in which they are defined, and so anything that was defined in the scope, in which the closure was also defined, will be known to that closure.

Also, the `addChangedValue` will have access to any variable in its enclosing scope *unless* you shadow it by defining a similarly-named variable within that function.

Comment: Thanks, today I read it in my JS book about nested functions which knows variables of the outer function :)

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous function that is an argument to `addChangedValue` forms a closure. The `sampleViewModel` is the same variable within the function as it is in the enclosing scope. A closure is a combination of a function (often anonymous, as in your case) with a context. All variables in scope when the function is declared are available within that function. You can read about closures [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've created a Closure. By example:

```
function init() {
    var person = { name: 'Joe' };

    var callMeLater = function() {
        alert(person.name);
    };

    return callMeLater;
};

var fn = init();
fn(); // alerts 'Joe'
```

In this example, the `init()` function has its own scope - which doesn't seem to be new to you. So for example person is declared inside of it, and therefore local to `init()`. `callMeLater` is defined inside this function, creating a Closure. All variables local to the enclosing function (`init`) are also available to `callMeLater`. And that's why the last line in this example alerts Joe, and your example makes `sampleViewModel` available.

It is as though in Java you did this:

```
public class Person {
    public string name;

    public Person(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public MyClosure getClosure() {
        string someOtherThing = "other";
        return new MyClosure(this, someOtherThing);
    }
}

public class MyClosure {
    public Person person;
    public string someOtherThing;

    public MyClosure(Person person, string someOtherThing) {
        this.person = person;
        this.someOtherThing = someOtherThing;
    }

    public void callMeLater() {
        log(person.name);
    }
}

var person = new Person("Joe");
var closure = person.getClosure();
closure.callMeLater(); // Logs "Joe"
```

You can think of the MyClosure class as being an implicit wrapper created for you by defining a function inside a function.